# UrlFetchApp with special character in url

Tags: google-apps-script

my script:

```
var Url = 'http://readonline.egscans.com/Remnant/Chapter_036_[END]';
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(Url).getContentText();
```

I get this error when I run my script.

> **"Invalid argument: http://readonline.egscans.com/Remnant/Chapter_036_[END]"**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can encode the URL using encodeURIComponent like this:

```
var Url = encodeURIComponent('http://readonline.egscans.com/Remnant/Chapter_036_[END]');
```

Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent